# Spring expression fails after upgrade to SpringBoot 2.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-expression-language

I had an application which was on SpringBoot 1.5.9.  I recently upgraded to SpringBoot 2.2.  I had a bunch of issues which I fixed, and now the app starts up without errors.

However, I have a @PreAuthorize on my controller methods which seems to be failing:

`@PreAuthorize("not @appConfig.getSecEnabled() or hasRole('ROLE')") public void someMethod() {}`

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'not @appConfig.getSecEnabled() or hasRole('ROLE')'`

What has changed in 2.2 that could cause this?